# How can I add a image banner on the bottom left of the wizard window?

Tags: inno-setup

[image: Image Banner on left]

How can I add an image to the setup wizard, the bottom left?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As @TLama commented:* Create a `TBitmapImage`, set its parent to `WizardForm`, position it where you want and load the picture from file.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "logo.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

<event('InitializeWizard')>
procedure InitializeWizardAddLogo();
var
  Image: TBitmapImage;
begin
  Image := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
  with Image do
  begin
    Parent := WizardForm;
    ExtractTemporaryFile('logo.bmp');
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\logo.bmp');
    AutoSize := True;
    AutoSize := False;
    Width := ScaleX(Width);
    Height := ScaleY(Height);
    Stretch := True;
    Left := ScaleX(10);
    Top :=
      (WizardForm.ClientHeight + WizardForm.Bevel.Top +
       WizardForm.Bevel.Height - Height)
      div 2;
  end;
end;
```

*(the code [with `event` attribute] is for Inno Setup 6)*

Though tricky part is to handle screen scaling correctly. Hence, the `AutoSize` trick and `Scale*` calls.

You even might need to have different versions of the logo for different scaling factors.
See [Inno Setup WizardImageFile looks bad with font scaling on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26543603/850848)

---

[image]