# Scaling image is not visible in welcome page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an customized welcome and finish pages with different images on both.
my issue is exactly similar to this question [Inno Setup WizardImageFile looks bad with font scaling on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543603/inno-setup-wizardimagefile-looks-bad-with-font-scaling-on-windows-7) and i have referred this solution
the installer is picking up the different images based on scaling(if scaling is 100% then it opt for 100, if 200% then 200).
but i want it should display on welcome page and finish page. but
1.My welcome page looks empty, i want the image should be displayed in welcome page.
2.The images is displaying in rest of the pages(like ready to install and others) at top left : but i don't want to display there.
3.At finish page it looks as i expected.
any ways here ?

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
WizardStyle=modern
DefaultDirName={autopf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=D:\repos\isetups
DisableWelcomePage=yes
; Use 100% images by default
WizardImageFile= WizardImage 100.bmp,WizardImage 125.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=WizardSmallImage 100.bmp,WizardSmallImage 125.bmp

[Files]
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme
Source: "WizardImage *.bmp"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "WizardSmallImage *.bmp";Flags: dontcopy

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

[Code]

function GetScalingFactor: Integer;
begin
if WizardForm.Font.PixelsPerInch >= 192 then Result := 200
else
if WizardForm.Font.PixelsPerInch >= 144 then Result := 150
else
if WizardForm.Font.PixelsPerInch >= 120 then Result := 125
else Result := 100;
end;

procedure LoadEmbededScaledBitmap(Image: TBitmapImage; NameBase: string);
var
Name: String;
FileName: String;
begin
Name := Format('%s %d.bmp', [NameBase, GetScalingFactor]);
log(Name);
ExtractTemporaryFile(Name);
FileName := ExpandConstant(Name);
Image.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(FileName);
//DeleteFile(FileName);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
WelcomePage: TWizardPage;

begin
WelcomePage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, '', '');
WelcomePageID := WelcomePage.ID;
BitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(WizardForm);
BitmapImage.Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
BitmapImage.Left := 0;
BitmapImage.Top := 0;
BitmapImage.AutoSize := True;
BitmapImage.Cursor := crHand;
BitmapImage.Visible := False;
begin
{ If using larger scaling, load the correct size of images }
if GetScalingFactor > 100 then
begin
LoadEmbededScaledBitmap(WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage, 'WizardImage');
LoadEmbededScaledBitmap(WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2, 'WizardImage');
LoadEmbededScaledBitmap(WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage, 'WizardSmallImage');
end;
end;
end;
```

Ready to install:
[image]

Welcome Page:
[image]

Comment: Where do you want to display the image on the welcome page? You put the image on the "inner page". There's no inner page on the welcome page. I do not see any image on your ready page either.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  yes I want to display image on the welcome page like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705492/custom-welcome-and-finished-page-with-stretched-image-in-inno-setup. it was displaying but not scaled one now it is displaying empty almost blank scree. and you can see a black box kind of thing at the top left in the corner in Ready page the image is compressed.

Comment: I do not see any of the code from that question in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show scaled and stretched image on the Welcome page:

- The code from this question will make the image stretch over whole (outter) page:
  [Custom Welcome and Finished page with stretched image in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34705492/850848)
- To scale the image, just give the [`WizardImageFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardimagefile) your set of scaled images, as described in the first part of my answer to
  [Inno Setup WizardImageFile looks bad with font scaling on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26543603/850848)
  You do not need any Pascal code for the scaling.